# google map not showing after publishing android application?

Tags: android, google-maps

friends,

while testing application on eclipse using emulator google map is being displayed properly.

but when i exported application to publish it.

google map is gone.

can any one guide me what mistake am i doing??

any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps v2 doesn't showing after publishing in play market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982327/google-maps-v2-doesnt-showing-after-publishing-in-play-market)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you exported your application to publish it, you are probably not using the debug keystore any more, but a custom one. (You cannot publish debug apps to Market). When you switch to another keystore, you will have to generate a new Google Maps API Key, based on that.

Comment: i have created debug keystore and that file of 1.32kb i have right now. but with no extension its just file.

should i get api key depending upon that keystore right?

Comment: If your app is published on the Market, you will have two keystores, the debug keystore and the production keystore you used to create the Market version of your app. The Google Maps API key is tied to the keystore you use to sign the app, so there is one Maps API key that you use when you sign with the debug keystore (i.e., normal development) and one Maps API key that you use when you sign with the production keystore (i.e., going to Market).

Answer (score 2):

After Exporting the Project,

- Step 1: Just Copy the SHA1 key and Get the New API_KEY from **Google Play Developer Console**
- Stet 2:Paste the API_KEY in your android Manifest file
- Step 3:Again exporting the same project to upload your final.apk use the existing          keystore