# I can't run my android maps aplication on phone

Tags: android, dictionary

I developed an android maps application on Google API 2.1 update-1 platform. And it is the simplest code to show a map on the screen, there is no other things.

However, map doesn't shown on phone. The problem is, the same program runs on my android emulator right but it is not working on my android phone properly, I mean program starts on phone but I see only greeds instead of map. phone android version is th same, 2.1 update-1.

Please help me,
Thanks.

Comment: this question has been asked over and over on stackoverflow. please use the search. obviously the google maps key is not correct.

Comment: @Mathias - read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq), see the section on "Be Nice", why not be helpful and provide a link if you think this is a dupe and let those with enough rep vote to close if need be.

Comment: @Kev ok, sorry, was just that I  replied to this question twice in the last 2 weeks or so (nicely :). Anyway, here's a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362913/google-map-not-showing-after-publishing-android-application (if signed with a key different than the debug key)... or as CommonsWare posted below...

Answer (score 0):

If the same APK file works on the emulator but does not work on the phone, ensure that:

- The phone has a working Internet connection
- The phone's built-in Maps application works