# google map in android emulator problem

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

instead of it displaying google map it only display grid view.

->   i followed all the steps that are in following sites examples
         http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android
                       or
         http://www.androidpeople.com/android-google-map-application-example/

->   i also set the proxy server
         run --> run configuration.. --> myapplication-->target tab--> additional command line

```
            -http-proxy http://192.68.100.101:8080/


 Still i am not getting the google map.
```

NOTE: i tried this in my mobile it works fine but not display in android emulator.

where i made mistake plz help me.

thank in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [google map not showing after publishing android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362913/google-map-not-showing-after-publishing-android-application)

Comment: with http proxy set in emulator as you specified, try accessing internet from the browser available in the emulator to make sure you are getting internet connection there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked very often here on SO, please try the search on SO:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+map+not+showing

Answer (score 0):

Check whether internet connection is available or not on your emulator by using any browser on it. This bugs basically comes under following possibilities

1. No internet Connection
2. Invalid Map Key

After checking these steps, try running your app again. If you know any other possibilities, share with this...