# Google map not showing?

Tags: android, google-maps

I got issue on google map integration.
This is my code to view google map.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<view android:id="@+id/mapView"
class="com.google.android.maps.MapView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:enabled="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:apiKey="0yNPIHMsyaw9rC_EpvaP333qD588HC16sA_C39A"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

When i load this application locally map showing in all mobiles except Nexus phone.
We uploaded application into Android market. But map not showing any of the android mobiles.

Can any one help me? Need to show map in all android version.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If someone solve your problem then accept his answer.You are getting solution to your problem without any fee.So please contribute and participate in community.People are not fool that you came only to ask question and if you got solution then forget about it.Even you have not accept your answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio - Google map still blank on real Android device on release apk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30559602/android-studio-google-map-still-blank-on-real-android-device-on-release-apk)

Answer (score 3):

You need to get MAP API key by using the **.keystore** file, which you are using for signing the API for uploading in the market. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362913/google-map-not-showing-after-publishing-android-application)