# Google maps v2 doesn't showing after publishing in play market

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, google-maps-api-2

i have some problem, my app works fine, but when i load it in Play market, maps does not works correctly. I make next:

1. Get SHA1 `keytool -list -v -keystore C:\User\Name/.android/debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android`
2. In Google console i create API KEY.  `SHA1;com.kostya.app`
3. Rigth click on project - Android tools - Export signed application packuage
4. Create new keystore and new *.apk file.
5. Load it into market.

Where is my mistake? I read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362913/google-map-not-showing-after-publishing-android-application). Together we can create nice tutorial how to sign app using google maps v2. How to test application at once after loading in play market, without weithing some ours.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When your are creating keystore for creating signed apk you have to do this.

1. change debug.keystore to your created keystore
2. change alias name to your project name
3. set the password the same like in your created keystore (not android as in debug mode)

   keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/ YOUR_KEYSTORE -alias YOUR_PROJECT_NAME

more help find [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

Comment: where i must  change it? in my step one?

Comment: are you created keystore for signed apk?

Comment: Yes, i have created it.

Comment: keytool -list -v -keystore ~/.android/ YOUR_KEYSTORE -alias YOUR_PROJECT_NAME  i make it now, i get SHA1, than i must go to google library and get api key?? What is the next step?

Comment: You must go to google create new key for your app with that SHA1

Comment: OK, now i must put new api key instead old api key in android manifest file? Or there can be two keys?

Comment: put  new key instead of old key

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37947/discussion-between-fish40-and-kostya-khuta)

Comment: Hi, I tried the above solution for same problem but I get error as "Alias <PROJECT_NAME> doesnot exist. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

after publishing the app on play store. 
on Google Play Console
Goto:
Release Management >App Signing
from "App signing certificate" copy SHA1 and paste it on Google cloud platform API console.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a production keystore, you should not use the debug.keystore.

Check out the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode).

Answer (score 1):

Just Add the apikey to debug>res>values>google_maps_api.xml

add in release>res>values>google_maps_api.xml  files.

Answer (score 0):

Just generate SHA1 using

**keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore**

go and add the package name and SHA1 fingerprint to the already generated

Answer (score 0):

I used Android studio to generate the release keystore. After tried many ways for two days I finally got this to work. The problem is that when generating signed APK in Android Studio either by choosing the existing keystore or creating a new one, the default format for the keystore file is ".jks". That is the problem. After I changed that to ".keystore" and generated the release apk, and then copied the SHA1 into google console. The map can finally be showing.

[image]
[image]