# Android Application not working after uploading in Play store

Tags: android, google-play

I have made an android app having a map which runs fine in emulator and mobile. And I signed it to upload in play store. I even zip aligned it. Then I uploaded it in the playstore. But the map doesn't load when I download it. I have been taking help from this site: http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

I have also followed the following two sites:
[Google maps v2 doesn't showing after publishing in play market](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982327/google-maps-v2-doesnt-showing-after-publishing-in-play-market)

[Google maps, Google store publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856197/google-maps-google-store-publish)

But still, it's not working. Its been a great problem for me. Please anyone, with a higher degree of knowledge, help me. I am in big trouble.

Comment: try to download app from play store and submit bug report than try resolve bug shown in your play store account.

Comment: have you updated your SHA! key in GOOGLE API Console for your project after signed your app with private keystore?.

Comment: Have you generated signed google map api key with SHA1 key and made google map feature available in google console?

Comment: I have done everything...the map load in emulator and mobil but after it has been downloaded it doesn't work.

Comment: @mystic_knight are you sure about that you have updated your new SHA1 key in API console? verify it is given SHA1 in Api console is for debug keystore or for Private keystore with you have signe dyour .APK

Comment: use this command and generate SHA1 key for your private keystore and verify is it same1 which you have provided in API Console? `keytool -list -v -keystore your_keystore_name with full path.keystore -alias your_alias_name` it will ask password enter that and then you will get SHA1 key

Comment: Don't wait til the app is available in the Play Store to download it; test the apk after you have _prepared_ it for the Play Store upload (i.e. after signing with your release credentials).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps v2 doesn't showing after publishing in play market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982327/google-maps-v2-doesnt-showing-after-publishing-in-play-market)

Comment: I ran into an issue with Amazon's LWA... wrote a blog entry about it. Maybe it will help: https://auri.net/2021/07/29/fix-app-no-longer-works-after-uploaded-to-google-play/

Answer (score 1):

- Check the version of google play services library and update it to the latest version.
- Then check the SHA1 key provided is the one you used to sign your application. If not provide the the correct key and try again.

Hope this can solve  the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The key you obtained and entered in the api console is for debugging purposes. You have to obtain sha1 key for the apk file from the Keystore file which you are using to digitally sign the apk

Procedure for obtaining SHA1 key for release mode

1) Go to the location where you have your 'keystore' file which you are using for digitally signing your application.

2) Open command window in that location. This can be done by 'shift+rightClick' and selecting the option 'Open Command Window here'

3) Use the following Command

```
keytool –v –list –keystore <name> -alias <aliasname>
```

where name- your keystore filename , aliasname - the alias name for the app

4) Then enter your keystore password

5) you will then get your sha1 keys along with other information. Use the key in the api console.

Answer (score 1):

If you got your app crashed after install from play store you must got a crash report.
Crash report contains the information for the reason of your app crashing.