# Google map v2 doesn't showing after publishing in play market

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play, google-maps-api-2

I have a problem with my google map in my android app after publishing.
In developer console I've enabled "Google Maps Android API v2", added SHA1 key + package:
**4D:8A:1F:C1:2D:8F:AD:EE:13:6A:AE:D0:FB:98:56:A1:76:70:84:2A;com.mypackage**, got API KEY and added it in android manifest.

But after I publish my app I got a message:

> Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled. Ensure that
>   the following Android Key exists: API Key:
>   AIzaSyBt8ERGTRg8dMQy62FHoDbhaVs7YrG52iA Android Application
>   (;):
>   **AA:08:25:A3:7B:3C:DD:C3:2D:7C:66:CE:67:47:8D:54:B9:3B:8A:21;com.mypackage**.

As you can see SHA1 in message and in my project are different. Why? Whats wrong?

Comment: Did you just post your SHA1 key for everyone to see?

Comment: Yep, it's just a test app. I will change my SHA1 if it needs

Comment: Did you already try [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27883587/google-maps-v2-not-working-in-production-with-correct-key)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google maps v2 doesn't showing after publishing in play market](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982327/google-maps-v2-doesnt-showing-after-publishing-in-play-market)